# Setting up Leap Motion frames for frame.translation

Tags: python-2.7, leap-motion

I am a very novice programmer and I have hit a wall with a side project I am working on. I am trying to set-up a loop to repeatedly get a translation array from movement across the leap motion. I found in the leap motion documentation this code for python:

```
linear_frame_movement = frame.translation(start_frame)
```

which by definition sounds like exactly what I need, but when I attempt to use this command in a very basic code, I'm not exactly understanding how to define the initial frame nor the reference frame. below is the section of code I am trying to get the frame.translation to be printed:

```
position = hand.palm_position
L = frame.translation(position, start_frame)
y = position
print "position: %s" % (L)
print "position1: %s" % (position)
```

This reports back with an error like "L = frame.translation(position, start_frame), more than 2 arguments listed".

Does this mean that only a start frame needed to be initialized then the command will determine translation arrays on its own, or do the 2 arguments need to be defined in a completely different way?

My coding background is in matlab, so python has be quiet foreign to me. My apologizes if this is a very straight forward question I am just missing. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

reading from the [documentation](https://developer-archive.leapmotion.com/documentation/python/api/Leap.Frame.html#Leap.Frame.translation), the translation method only requires one input which is the inital frame that the translation will be referenced from (hence, start_frame variable name). This will be a valid frame obtained before the current frame.

you do not have to reference the current frame as the translation method is within the current frame object - frame.translation().

the return is 0 if either the current frame or start_frame is invalid 
*(this is checked using the attribute frame.is_valid which returns a Boolean).*

Otherwise, the return is a [vector](https://developer-archive.leapmotion.com/documentation/python/api/Leap.Vector.html) class. The vector class will give the translations of objects in the x and y direction *(which can be obtained using the attributes vector.x and vector.y)*, in reference to the current frame. Therefore, a previous objects position could be determined by translating the current objects position using the return vector.

This can simply be done by taking away the x and y values of the translation vector from the current objects position x and y values. This can be done also in reverse. I havent tested this out, so im unsure if it is the right method.

Hope this helps!